# Does an item effect still occur if you go insanse/unconscious using it?

Tags: arkham-horror

As an example, an investigator had the item `Flute of The Outer Gods`, which takes 3 stamina and 3 sanity to use and immedietly defeats all monsters in the investigators location. If using the item reduced either the sanity or stamina to 0, does the effect still come in to effect?

Does this apply to all items that require you to lose either sanity or stamina?

This question is **not** a duplicate of: [How does Flute of the Outer Gods work in Arkham Horror and when should I use/buy it?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3543/how-does-flute-of-the-outer-gods-work-in-arkham-horror-and-when-should-i-use-buy) although the answer there is relavent.

This question is asking about items in general and not just the `Flute of The Outer Gods`

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of [In Arkham Horror, can you pay sanity costs to go insane on purpose?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7668/in-arkham-horror-can-you-pay-sanity-costs-to-go-insane-on-purpose). I'm not sure because the question is somewhat different, although the answer covers this question.

Comment: The answer in the question you linked does seem to address this, however as you already stated, this question is different as it is asking about item effects whereas the other is asking if the player can intentionally go insane

Comment: The question is different, but the answer most definitely applies. I don't see how it doesn't. Kevin Wilson's answer encompasses this.

Comment: @generalcrispy The fact that another answer answers this question does not make the *question* a duplicate.  Would anybody trying to find the answer to this automatically think of looking for "can you go insane on purpose"?  I wouldn't.  (Referring to the same post by Kevin Wilson would be an acceptable answer to this!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a cost associated with a spell or exhaust card leaves you at 0 stamina or 0 sanity it will resolve before you become injured or insane at the location you cast it.

What about Flute of the Outer Gods? 
After the injury or madness, the spell resolves(Either its success or failure state) in the location in which it was cast the spell.

You then become injured or insane and are transported to the correct treatment facility.

Other spells that does not have such dramatic effects (Like plus to combat checks) are rendered useless since you can not perform a combat check after the spell has resolved against the original target which resides in another location.